# Startup Problems

Tags: raspbian, boot, kodi

So I have only used my raspberry pi 2 a couple of times and worked perfectly with Raspbian and KODI.  But now I went to use it this afternoon after school and found it wasn't turning on (only red light)...  Then there was my KODI card, it was flashing the green light with a red light constantly (then lots of solid red without green) on and Flickering on the display was the main rainbowy Square Image that appears on startup normally, however on for 3 seconds ish then off for 5 ish etc and did this until I turned it off.  The only thing I could put it down to is being unplugged incorrectly (suddenly) and it has build in heatsinks (the case does anyway :-)  )  PLEASE HELP, Want to start working on my media center.  Thanks Heaps Guys :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these:

1. Use a proper power supply (5 volt, 2-3 A).
2. Add `boot_delay=1` to `/boot/config.txt`

Comment: ok used boot_dely=1 but still just flashing (but this time on noobs so improvement :-)  )  I will purchase a power supply and try that... I am just using an apple ipad usb socket with my old phone charger usb :p

Comment: sorry; there was a typo here (delay, not dely). The correct code is `boot_delay=1`

Comment: Glad to hear it works. But buying a proper power supply is also highly recommended. Also, if the answer helped you, you may want to accept it.